# How to create a label for a Yeti Cup

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, shapes

I am attempting to vinyl wrap a cup with the initials 'RBN' on it but the cup is not a perfect cylinder. I need to know how to design this so that when printed and wrapped the letters appear to look straight.

Top Circumference - 11 inches
Bottom Circumference - 9 inches

Height 9 inches.

Comment: Your design is going to be an *unwrapped truncated cone*. I was going to do [the maths](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.02.06/phil1.html) but it's really late over here ...

Comment: So I actually had to do this today and I am not the best at math so I found this website that builds the template for you at [Template Maker](http://www.templatemaker.nl/index.php?template=cone&lang=).